# Inverted PWM with ATTiny10

Tags: pwm, atmel, attiny

On a 10MHz ATTiny10, the following code generates the same 40kHz 50% duty PWM on both pins 0 and 1:

```
DDRB = (1 << PB0) | (1 << PB1); //Output on PB0 and PB1
TCCR0A = (1 << COM0A0) | (1 << COM0B0); //Toggle OC0A and OC0B on compare match
TCCR0B = (1 << CS00) | (1 << WGM02); //Clear on compare, use unscaled clock
OCR0A = (1000000L /40000 / 2) - 1; //Overflow twice per 40kHz period
OCR0B = (1000000L /40000 / 2) - 1; //Overflow twice per 40kHz period
```

I want pin 1 to be exactly inverted: both pins should be PWM 40kHz 50% duty, but inverted of each other. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use wavegen mode 14, set `COM0Ax` to 0b10 and `COM0Bx` to 0b11, and adjust `ICR0`, `OCR0A`, and `OCR0B` to give 40kHz 50% DC.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to get the exact inverted PWM signal is to generate one signal with the MCU pin and then use an external inverter chip to logically invert the signal. A chip like a 74HC04 may be in order.

Comment: I would not have asked the question if I could have accepted an external component...